# Arrays in C, and Loops

Tags: c, arrays

```
int main()
{
int marks[3];
int counter=0;
for (i in marks){
     printf(marks[i];
         counter=counter+1;
}
return 0

}
```

Very new to C, although I know Python. I don't know the syntax, but I'm trying to create and array, then print each variable in the array. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is `counter` and what is it doing there?

Comment: `for` doesn't work the same way in C as it does in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_MARKS 3
int main()
{
    int marks[NUM_MARKS];
    /* marks contains all undefined data */
    int counter=0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_MARKS; i++){
         printf("%d\n", marks[i]);
         counter++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#define` - eek! I prefer the `i < sizeof marks / sizeof marks [0]` method.

Comment: Or: `enum { NUM_MARKS = 3 };`...the advantage being that the size is then a symbol in the symbol table for debugging, whereas `#define` does not show up in the debugger.

Comment: Yep, either of those probably preferred, but given the OPs level of knowledge, I thought a #define was the better choice in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

1. That's not how you do a `for` loop in C. See my example. And search google or SO.
2. You missed a closing bracket on the `printf` line.
3. You missed a semicolon `;` after `return 0`.
4. You didn't define any data in the array.
5. `printf` takes a string, not an int as it's first argument.

   ```
   int main()
   {
       int marks[] = {1, 2, 3};
       int i;
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           printf("%d", marks[i]);
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

assuming C99 support.  Without C99 support,

```
int i;
for (i =0; i < 3; i++)
```

You can also use `NUM_MARKS` in place of the 3:

```
enum { NUM_MARKS = 3 };
int marks[NUM_MARKS];
```

or:

```
enum { NUM_MARKS = sizeof(marks) / sizeof(marks[0]) };
```

The net result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

C does not have foreach type loops as Python does.  You can't just assume that language A works like language B.  You need:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(marks) / sizeof(marks[0]); ++i) {
    printf("%d\n", marks[i]);
}
```

If you're working in VS (and actually compiling as C) then  you'll need to declare all of your variables at the top of the function.  C99 changed this, but unfortunately MS will never support C99.